# Grails/Groovy : custom Transactional exceptions

Tags: grails, transactions

Sorry I have updated the question, because its quite a trivial question and I should have highlighted actual concerns on here.

Thinking about it, the only advantage would be in logs or for the sake of tracibility having such custom exceptions would probably of use..

I have put this demo project together for grails: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/test-transactions which was ported over from a Java example found here: https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/08/31/jotm-transactions-in-spring-and-hibernate.html

I still need to work on it but at the moment I was trying to find the best approach/practice since I don't think the content of the groovy exceptions is as clean as it should be (a little more Java looking than groovy)

[example below source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vahidhedayati/test-transactions/master/src/groovy/com/example/exception/FlightNotFoundException.groovy)

```
package com.example.exception

class FlightNotFoundException  extends TravelException {

    public FlightNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message)
    }

    public FlightNotFoundException(Exception e) {
        super(e.getMessage())
    }

}
```

Is this even correct way of doing an Exception class in groovy ?

[source code](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/test-transactions/blob/master/grails-app/services/com/example/FlightManagerService.groovy#L14)

```
class FlightManagerService {

@Transactional
def reserveFlight(BookingRequest bookingRequest) throws FlightNotFoundException {
...
}
```

it gets used in this service and each of these services throws a custom Exception as I said I can see the only advantage would be to trace later which or what was the exception.. but is this all really necessary I mean a simple log.info/error would report which service failed or was throwing exception anyways..

so rather than all that try I think I should really mess around but still worth clearing up just to find better practice. Thinking back to grails trainsaction video I should really remove all the try catches and possibly replace the throwable service actions to :

```
new domainClass(name: "something", value: 'another').save()
        throw new RuntimeException("Issue saving domainClass")
```

Any input appreciated

Updated to add

After conversating with Joshua

```
@Transactional
 def someThing() { 
    domainInstance.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}
```

should suffice without all the fancy work.. (will do some experimentation when and update the git project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using exceptions for non-exceptional cases. You are trying to use them for logic, and business rules. While this is very common, it's a very common abuse of exceptions in general.

In the best case you should strive to have code that does not use exceptions for flow control. They should only be used in cases where something exceptional (e.g. not expected behavior) occurs.

However, that said, if you do continue on you will want to make sure you don't include the stack traces. Grails has huge stack traces and filling them in in your exceptions is going to be a huge performance hit. You can avoid doing so by adding the following to your custom exceptions:

```
/**
* Don't fill in the stack trace because we want things to be faster.
**/
@Override
public Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
    // do nothing
    return this
}
```

Comment: Hey Joshua, thanks.. Its probably where I just imitated the Java example and hence the question of best practice. In regards to the service doing a throwable is ok ? maybe i should add to this too? @Transactional(Transactional(rollbackFor=FlightNotFoundException.class)

Comment: By default, any transaction thrown by a service in Grails will mark the transaction for rollback (provided there is a transaction and the service method is called through the transactionally wrapped proxy), so you don't need to be that specific.

Comment: Not true - only unchecked exceptions roll back transactions by default. You can add properties to the @Transactional annotation to specify which checked exceptions should trigger a rollback and/or unchecked exceptions that should not. Just because Groovy plays tricks with checked exceptions to make our lives easier doesn't mean that non-Groovy frameworks like Spring can or will play along

Comment: Thank you Burt. I misspoke. Hope you had a nice time in Spain at Greach!

Comment: Amazing, thank you both for your great feedbacks / answers. I have now updated that demo project and its mostly working i.e. it still needs work. It might be a nice tutorial to post up to grails site once its all done. It probably will be of great use to others.